# Merge multiple text data frames to view words that corresponds to each other

Tags: r, text, merge, dataframe

Overview:
I have the above 3 data frames. I want the end results as the final_merge_df.

Details:
I have many tables such the ones below. I would like to merge all tables into one table (as below: “final_merge_df”). Each table has the same format but different data.
In each table, there are two columns. In the first column, there is one word per row. All tables has the same words but there might be any number of words per table. Also, note that there might be tables that contain zero rows with a particular word.
The second column has a word that corresponds to the first word (for what ever reason). However, there is only one word in each of the second column, and the word in the second column might be same or different from the word in the first column.
Each of the second columns might have words that do not exists in any other table’s second column.

```
df1 = data.frame( 
  x1=c("bus","bus","cat","cat"),
  df1=c("bus","driver","mouse","dog"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

>df1
   x1      df1
1 bus      bus
2 bus   driver
3 cat    mouse
4 cat      dog

df2 = data.frame(
  x1=c("bus","bus","bus","cat","cat"),
  df2=c("car","driver","bus","dog","paw"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

>df2
   x1      df2
1 bus      car
2 bus   driver
3 bus      bus
4 cat      dog
5 cat      paw

df3 = data.frame(
  x1=c("bus","bus","cat","cat","cat","cat"),
  df3=c("bus","autobus","dog","bed","paw","tree"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df3
  x1         df3
1 bus        bus
2 bus    autobus
3 cat        dog
4 cat        bed
5 cat        paw
6 cat       tree
```

I want one table that is a merge of all other tables (see below).
The first column, again, contains the same words that each of the first columns of the original tables has.
The second column contain words from the second column in the second table. The third column contains the words from the third table, and the fourth columns contains the words from the fourth table and so on.
If, in each of the 2nd to Nth column, if the word in that column corresponds (as in the original table) to the word in the first column, the write the word in.  If it doesn’t correspond, then write “”.

For instance, look at first row in the output. All three original tables has the word “bus” and the word “bus” corresponds to the word “bus”. Look at the second row: tables 1 and 2 contains the word “driver” which corresponds to the word “bus”, while the 3rd table does not contain the word “driver” and therefore we write in “”.

```
# this is an example of how the result should look from the examples tables above
final_merge_df = data.frame(
  x1  = c(rep("bus",4), rep("cat",5)),
  df1 = c("bus","driver","<NA>","<NA>",   "mouse","dog","<NA>","<NA>","<NA>"),
  df2 = c("bus","driver","car", "<NA>",   "<NA>", "dog","paw", "<NA>","<NA>"),
  df3 = c("bus","<NA>",  "<NA>","autobus","<NA>", "dog","paw", "bed", "tree"))

>final_merge_df
  x1       df1      df2        df3
1 bus      bus      bus        bus
2 bus   driver   driver       <NA>
3 bus     <NA>      car       <NA>
4 bus     <NA>     <NA>    autobus
5 cat    mouse     <NA>       <NA>
6 cat      dog      dog        dog
7 cat     <NA>      paw        paw
8 cat     <NA>     <NA>        bed
9 cat     <NA>     <NA>       tree
```

I have tried a bunch of things including:

```
df = merge( df1, df2, by.x="df1", by.y="df2", all=T)

>df
      df1  x1.x x1.y
1     bus   bus  bus
2     car  <NA>  bus
3     dog   cat  cat
4  driver   bus  bus
5   mouse   cat <NA>
6     paw  <NA>  cat
```

Based on the above output, I wrote a short function that transformed df to:

```
   x1       df1      df2
1 bus       bus      bus
4 bus    driver   driver
2 bus      <NA>      car
3 cat       dog      dog
5 cat     mouse     <NA>
6 cat      <NA>      paw
```

which is exactly what I want but it only works for two tables.  I need a way where I can handle more than 2 tables.

I also tried a few frequency tables conversation and also creating a termdocumentmatrix (using the tm package) but no success.

I am very grateful for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm short in time. So this is not very elegant solution, but it works.

```
df1 = data.frame( 
  x1=c("bus","bus","cat","cat"),
  df1=c("bus","driver","mouse","dog"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 = data.frame(
  x1=c("bus","bus","bus","cat","cat"),
  df2=c("car","driver","bus","dog","paw"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df3 = data.frame(
  x1=c("bus","bus","cat","cat","cat","cat"),
  df3=c("bus","autobus","dog","bed","paw","tree"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

s <- function(df) {
  split(df[,2], df[,1])
}

l <- lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), s)

n <- unique(unlist(lapply(l, names)))

m <- do.call(rbind, lapply(n, function(i) {
  tmp <- lapply(l, "[[", i)
  u <- unique(unlist(tmp))
  cbind(rep(i, length(u)), u, sapply(tmp, function(x) u %in% x))
}))

m

m2 <- t(apply(m, 1, function(i) ifelse(i[3:length(i)], i[2], NA)))

as.data.frame(cbind(m[,1], m2))
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, @DrDom.  The reply is correct but because I was not clear enough in my question (I apologize), I had to make one change in the case where a new table (df4) has a word (x1) that is not in the other tables.  My fix: under your `tmp <- lapply(l, "[[", i)`, I added `for( j in 1:length(tmp) ) { if( is.null( tmp[[j]][1] )) { tmp[[j]][1] = "unique_word" } }`.  The reason for this line is to pad the tmp list to get the correct number of rows. Otherwise the rbind() will error.Then at the bottom, I had to remove columns with the "unique_word", which is not a big deal.

Comment: My solution should work with any number of data.frames which are simultaneously passed as a list. If you need to add data.frames sequentially then of course the proposed solution will not work as is.

Comment: Your solution works perfect with any number of data frames (I tried it).  It was just this one special case, which I didn't mention in my original question, where I had to fix. The bottom line is that without your help, I wouldn't be as far ahead as I am today with this problem so thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

can I give it a try? If I am saying something wrong, let me know. I am happy to withdraw my answer. If I am not mistaken, I think you are saying that you want to make your approach work for three data frames, which works for two data frames. I thought about doing something `Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, all = TRUE), list(df1,df2,df3)`. But, I could not think any. (I guess some experts will be able to offer something in this line.) So, I decided to go through the merge processes in the following way. This is a problem-specific approach,and this is probably not how experts here would handle your challenge. But, at least this allows you to have a data frame which you can apply your function and come up with your desired outcome.

```
library(dplyr)
### I follow your script.
df = merge(df1, df2, by.x="df1", by.y="df2", all=T)
df <- arrange(df, df1)

### I want to repeat the same procedure, but two colums with bus and cat 
### won't help. So I drop x1.y in df which comes from df2.

### Separate the df2 part (x1.y)
foo <- df$x1.y

### Create df1 (new version)
ana <- select(df, df1, x1.x)

### This is merge with the new version of df1 and df3
bob = merge(ana, df3, by.x="df1", by.y="df3", all=T)

### There are three new items (i.e., autobus, bed, and tree).
### They are in df3, but not df2.
### So, I added NA in the positions of the items in df2.

foo2 <- c(NA, NA, foo, NA)

### Now add the df2 part.
cathy <- cbind(bob, foo2)
names(cathy) <- c("whatever", "df1", "df3", "df2")

### Reorder columns
david <- cathy[,c(1,2,4,3)]

#> david
#  whatever  df1  df2  df3
#1  autobus <NA> <NA>  bus
#2      bed <NA> <NA>  cat
#3      bus  bus  bus  bus
#4      car <NA>  bus <NA>
#5      dog  cat  cat  cat
#6   driver  bus  bus <NA>
#7    mouse  cat <NA> <NA>
#8      paw <NA>  cat  cat
#9     tree <NA> <NA>  cat
```